# Django: How to Iterate over an Object one by one in my View?

Tags: django, templates, view

I am trying to write a Quiztool with Django. I have created an index where all surveys are listed. Clicking at one brings you in the detail view. Right now there are listed all questions with answers with a submit button going to nothing. What i am asking for is how to manage there will be only one question and when I submit the answer the next question will aply wihtout jumpin out of the detail view. If the answer is to easy i also would be happy for just getting a hint about what I have to read...

Here is some Code from my views.py

```
def detail(request, survey_id):
    #try:

    question = Survey.objects.get(pk=survey_id).question.all()

    question_dict = {
      'question': question,
    }
    return render(request, 'survey/detail.html', question_dict)
```

And here is my deatil.html

```
{% if question %}
    <form method="post">
    {% for x in question %}
    <fieldset style="width:10%;">
      <legend>{{x.question_text}}</legend>
      {% for y in x.answer.all %}
        <p style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;">
        <label for="{{ y.answer_id }}">{{ y.answer_text }}</label>
        <input name="{{x.question_id}}" type="radio" value="{{y.answer_id}}" id="{{y.answer_id}}"/></p>
      {% endfor%}
    </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="button" value="Senden" onclick="var Sende=()=>{console.log('gesendet');}; Sende();">
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No questions are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And my Model

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_id = models.AutoField(blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    answer_text = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=500, verbose_name=_(u'Text der Antwort'))

    # Internal fields
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_(u'Erstellt am'))
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True, verbose_name=_(u'Geändert am'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

    class Meta:
        # db_table = 'data'
        verbose_name = _(u'Antwort')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Antworten')
        ordering = ['answer_id']

class Question(models.Model):
    question_id = models.AutoField(blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    # Fields

    answer = models.ManyToManyField('Answer', through='Question_Answer', related_name='+')
    question_text = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=500, verbose_name=_(u'Text der Frage'))

    # Internal fields
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_(u'Erstellt am'))
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True, verbose_name=_(u'Geändert am'))
    #Typunterscheidung der Fragen

    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        ('0', 'Vezweigt'),
        ('1', 'Wahr/Falsch'),
        ('2', 'Punkte'),
        ('3', 'Umfrage'),
    )

    type_id = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=1, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
    # String

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    # Meta class
    class Meta:
        # db_table = 'data'
        verbose_name = _(u'Frage')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Fragen')
        ordering = ['question_id']

# Hilfstabelle für many to many Feld mit informationen für die Frage Logik
class Question_Answer(models.Model):
    question_answer_id = models.AutoField(blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+')
    answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer', related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_correct = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False, verbose_name=_(u'Richtige Antwort'))
    next_question = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'Naechste Frage(Verzw.)'))
    points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'Wertigkeit der Antwort'))


class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_id = models.AutoField(blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    question = models.ManyToManyField('Question', through='Survey_Question', related_name='+')
    survey_titel = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=500, verbose_name=_(u'Titel des Fragebogens'))

    class Meta:
        # db_table = 'data'
        verbose_name = _(u'Fragebogen')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Fragebögen')
        ordering = ['survey_id']

class Survey_Question(models.Model):
    survey_question_id = models.AutoField(blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey('Survey', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+')
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, verbose_name=_(u'Rangfolge der Antwort'))
```

Thank you in advance Flotzen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straightforward approach would be to keep your code the same in Django, and use Javascript to handle what the user sees on the browser. Then, upon completion, you can submit the answers like a traditional form post.

Comment: I have feared this answer now i have to look how javascript works and to get it connected with my django....

Comment: Lol I remember this feeling when I was first learning Django. If you have the time, it is well worth it. Otherwise, you can look at other options like Paginator like @Alper mentioned or other pagination options. You might also be able to get that to work. Doing it with Javascript (IMO) though would be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like something where you would throw your objects into a `Paginator` (with `per_page of 1) and then you could walk through them.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/

Comment: but how can I post with pagination -.-